# If $A=\begin{bmatrix} 1 &2&0 \\ 2&1&0 \\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$, find the trace of $A^{20}$

Tags: matrices

$$A^2=\begin {bmatrix} 5&4&0 \\ 4&5&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$
And $$A^3 =\begin{bmatrix} 13&14&0 \\ 14&13&0 \\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} $$
And
$$A^4 =\begin{bmatrix} 41&40&0 \\40&41&0 \\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$

And so on

unfortunately, I am unable to detect a pattern in this series of matrices, which is required for further computation. How should I proceed?

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion of an eigenvalue of a matrix?

Comment: diagonalize and then apply the fact that trace is preserved by similarity

Comment: @richrow not yet

Comment: Actually there is a pattern! Note that the trace of the matrix is $3^n + (-1)^n + 1^n$. Why those numbers as the bases of the exponential terms? They are the eigenvalues of this matrix!

Comment: @paulinho can this expression be obtained without knowing what eigen values of a matrix are?

Comment: @Aditya Unfortunately I don’t think so.

Comment: See my answer. There is a pattern and you can solve the recursion to find all the terms of any power of $A$.

Comment: To find the value of $A^{20}$ directly, you can use [binary exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). $20_{10} = 10100_2$ so the calculation proceeds: start with $A$, square it to get $A^2$, square again ($A^4$), multiply by $A$ ($A^5$), square again ($A^{10}$), square again ($A^{20}$). Five calculations and you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :** $(A^n)_{11} = 3 \times (A^{n-1})_{11} + 2 \times(-1)^{n}$.

Then solve the recursion : it gives you $$(A^n)_{11} = 3^n + (-1)^{n-1} \frac{1-(-3)^n}{2}$$

Noticing that $(A^n)_{22} = (A^n)_{11}$ and $(A^n)_{33} = 1$, you should be able to conclude.

Comment: How does this give answer as $3^{20}+2$, since we will always require the penultimate term

Comment: I edited my answer, with more details.

Comment: What process did you apply on the recursion? I have no clue on how you obtained that

Comment: You mean, how did I extract $(A^n)_{11}$ from the recursion formula ? I wrote the first terms and saw a pattern appear... But to prove it formally from the recursion formula, use an induction.

Comment: Well, an induction will definitely prove it, but my main concern is on how to obtain it. But all this discussion makes me think that this is beyond my scope of study at the moment

Comment: It is easier than you think. To simplify the notations, let $u_n = (A^n)_{11}$. You have $u_1 = 3u_0 + 2$. Then $u_2 = 3(3u_0+2)-2 = 9u_0 + 3*2-2$. Then $u_3 = 3(9u_0 + 3*2-2) + 2 = 27u_0 + 9*2-3*2 + 2$ and so on. You see appear that $u_n = 3^nu_0 + \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} 3^k *2*(-1)^{n-1-k}$, and you can simplify the geometric sum to get the formula I gave you.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the matrix is diagonalizable, so that $A=SDS^{-1}$
with $D=\operatorname{diag}(3,1,-1)$. Then
$$
A^n=SD^nS^{-1},
$$
and $D^n$ is very easy to compute. Hence we have
for all $n\ge 1$,
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^n)=3^n+1+(-1)^n.
$$

Comment: I am not aware what diagonalization means

Comment: It means $A=SDS^{-1}$ and $D$ is a diagonal matrix.

Comment: And what are $S$ and $S^{-1}$ here?

Comment: $S$ is an invertible matrix with inverse matrix $S^{-1}$ such that $A=SDS^{-1}$ and $D$ is diagonal. There may be many such matrices $S$, but we can find just one particular $S$.

Comment: @Aditya To understand diagonalization you need to understand eigenvalues and eigenvectors. The key takeaway is that if you have a diagonal matrix $D$ which is similar to $A$ a power of $A$ is easy to compute. Any matrix $A$ that is symmetric, i.e. $A=A^T$ is diagonalizable, i.e. there exists a diagonal matrix $D$ that is similar to $A$.

Comment: @david that’s my problem, I am not aware about the concept of eigen vectors currently. Can this question be done without applying to those concepts?

Comment: Yes, sure. Just put the matrix to a computer. Then $$A^{20}=\begin{pmatrix} 1743392201  & 1743392200  &0 \cr 1743392200  & 1743392201  & 0 \cr  0 & 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: @Aditya Since you have already calculated $A^4$ you can calculate $A^4A^4$ to get $A^8$ then calculate $A^{16}=A^8A^8$ then calculate $A^{20}=A^{16}A^4$. I recommend to study eigenvectors and eigenvalues though.

Comment: I agree with David. The idea of this exercise is to come to learn about eigenvalues. Otherwise the exercise is a bit useless. And since you know already about the sum of the eigenvalues, the trace, this seems only appropriate.

Comment: @david well David, thanks for letting me know. Obviously, multiplying all the matrices defies ergonomics, I will try to apply those concepts

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is

$$(a_{1,1})_{n}+(a_{1,2})_{n}=3^n$$

and

$$(a_{1,1})_{n}+(a_{2,2})_{n}=(a_{1,1})_{n}+(a_{1,2})_{n}+(-1)^{n+1}=3^n+(-1)^{n+1}$$

which can be proved by induction, therefore

$$Tr(A^n)=(a_{1,1})_{n}+(a_{2,2})_{n}+1=3^n+(-1)^{n+1}+1$$

Answer (score 0):

From your calculations, I hope it is clear that $\text{Trace}(A^n)=1+\text{Trace}(B^n)$
where
$$B=\pmatrix{1&2\\2&1}.$$
Write $t_n=\text{Trace}(B^n)$.
Now,
$$B^2=\pmatrix{5&4\\4&5}=2B+3I$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix. Multiplying by $B^n$ gives
$$B^{n+2}=2B^{n+1}+3B^n$$
and if we take traces we get
$$t_{n+2}=2t_{n+1}+3t_n.$$
This is a recurrence, with initial conditions $t_0=t_1=2$ that can be solved
by your favourite method of solving recurrences.

Here's another approach. Note that $B=I+2C$ where
$$C=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}.$$
Then $C^2=I$ and so $C^k=I$ when $k$ is even and $C^k=C$ when $C$ is odd.
Therefore
$$B^n=(I+2C)^n=I+2nC+2^2{n\choose 2}C^2+2^3{n\choose 3}C^3+
\cdots+2^n{n\choose n}C^n.$$
Take the trace, noting that $\text{Trace}(C^k)=2$ when $k$ is even
and $\text{Trace}(C^k)=0$ when $k$ is odd:
$$t_n=2\left(1+{n\choose 2}2^2+{n\choose 4}2^4+\cdots\right).\tag{1}$$
But the binomial theorem gives
$$(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n=2\left(1+{n\choose 2}x^2+{n\choose 4}x^4+\cdots\right)\tag{2}$$
so if we set $x=2$ in $(2)$ we can evaluate $(1)$.

Answer (score 0):

Note:
$$\begin{vmatrix} 1-\lambda &2&0 \\ 2&1-\lambda&0 \\0&0&1-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=0 \Rightarrow (1-\lambda)((1-\lambda)^2-4)=0 \Rightarrow \lambda_1=1,\lambda_2=-1,\lambda_3=3;\\
B=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&0\\ 0&1&0\\ 0&0&3 \end{pmatrix};\\
(A-\lambda I)X=0 \stackrel{\lambda =1}{\Rightarrow} \begin{cases}2x_2=0\\ 2x_1=0\\ \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}0\\ 0\\ 1\end{pmatrix}\\
(A-\lambda I)X=0 \stackrel{\lambda =-1}{\Rightarrow} \begin{cases}2x_1+2x_2=0\\ 2x_1+2x_2=0\\ 2x_3=0 \end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}-1\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\\
(A-\lambda I)X=0 \stackrel{\lambda =3}{\Rightarrow} \begin{cases}-2x_1+2x_2=0\\ 2x_1-2x_2=0\\ -2x_3=0\end{cases}\Rightarrow \begin{pmatrix}1\\ 1\\ 0\end{pmatrix}\\
S=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 0&1&0 \end{pmatrix},S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-0.5&0.5&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0.5&0.5&0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Verify [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B1%2C2%2C0%7D%2C%7B2%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%7D).

So: $A=SBS^{-1}$. Verify [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%7D%7B%7B-1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C3%7D%7D%7B%7B-0.5%2C0.5%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0.5%2C0.5%2C0%7D%7D).

Use the formula: $A^n=SB^nS^{-1}$.
$$A^{20}=SB^{20}S^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&0&1\\ 1&0&1\\ 0&1&0 \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}(-1)^{20}&0&0\\ 0&1^{20}&0\\ 0&0&3^{20} \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-0.5&0.5&0\\ 0&0&1\\ 0.5&0.5&0 \end{pmatrix}=...$$
Can you finish yourself?

Answer:

> $$\begin{pmatrix}0.5(3^{20}+1)&0.5(3^{20}-1)&0\\ 0.5(3^{20}-1)&0.5(3^{20}+1)&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1743392201&1743392200&0\\ 1743392200&1743392201&0\\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}$$

Verify [Wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B-1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%7D%7B%7B1%2C0%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C3%5E20%7D%7D%7B%7B-0.5%2C0.5%2C0%7D%2C%7B0%2C0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0.5%2C0.5%2C0%7D%7D).

Answer (score 0):

Let $B=\pmatrix{1&2\\ 2&1}$. Then $B^2=2B+3I_2=0$, i.e. $(B+I)(B-3I)=0$. It follows that if
$$
x^{20}=(x+1)(x-3)q(x)+(cx+d)\tag{1}
$$
then $B^{20}=cB+dI_2$. By substituting $x=-1$ and $x=3$ respectively into $(1)$, we get $-c+d=(-1)^{20}=1$ and $3c+d=3^{20}$. Hence $2(c+d)=3^{20}+1$ and
$$
\operatorname{tr}(A^{20})
=\operatorname{tr}\pmatrix{B^{20}\\ &1}
=\operatorname{tr}(B^{20})+1
=\operatorname{tr}(cB+dI_2)+1
=2(c+d)+1=3^{20}+2.
$$